# SemanticUI- columns inside <tbody> of table are not getting stacked

Tags: html, semantic-ui

The columns inside `<tbody>` are not getting stacked
[image: When not stacked]

[image: When stacked]

```
<table class="ui very basic collapsing selectable celled single line table" style="width:100%;">
                                  <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Title</th>
                                        <th>Average Score</th>
                                        <th>Weighted Mean</th>
                                        <th>Percentile</th>
                                        <th>Submitted By</th>
                                    </tr>
                                  </thead>
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td><h4> Customer User</h4></td>
                                      <td>Average Score: 22</td>
                                      <td>Weighted Mean: 22</td>
                                      <td>Percentile: 22</td>
                                      <td>Submitted by: User 4325</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
```

I am trying to find a solution for this for long but could not get anything.
Please help

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you want to achieve and what you get instead? You want things "stacked" horizontally or vertically? The screenshots are confusing, since they show different behaviour in the `thead`, while your complaint is about the `tbody`. And I put your code in [a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/jzxs5z66/1/), but its result looks different from either of the screenshots. (Although that could be just my inexperience with semantic ui.) So you should also post what css you used.

Comment: The code is working fine is jsFiddle, can there be any problem with the version of semantic ui I am using? I am using semantic UI with meteor js and I am using angular-meteor